# asp.net core apache Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, apache, asp.net-core, internal-server-error

I am trying to deploy an ASP.net Core 3.1 app to a server with apache2 installed. I have created the following virtualhost:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
    #ServerAdmin mail@mail.com
    ServerName xx.app
    ServerAlias www.xx.app
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}xx-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}xx-access.log common


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.app/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.app/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

when i run the application (using dotnet .dll), i get the following message:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/cv/web/publish
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Then when i try to browse the app I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

When I view the logs the only thing that I find is:

```
AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL / (scheme 'http'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

I have tried to enable the mods proxy_http, http and it didn't fix the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the virtual host needed these two lines at the start:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

and these lines at the virtualhost *443:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
```